# No "Convert to C/C++ Project" in eclipse plugin though CDT is installed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-2019-03

With the CDT Plugin comes an option to convert Projects into C/C++ Projects. That changes a few entries in the `.project` file. For example, the entries

```
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
```

are added. If I manually add them, I can see that the syntax highlighting changes to C syntax. But other things don't work correctly (details aren't important, but you can read them [here](http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/Ccontents-of-wrong-file-displayed-in-CContentOutlinePage-if-two-editors-with-the-same-name-are-opened-td203013.html)).

I can see the menu inside eclipse, but not when running my eclipse plugin. In the Configuration menu I have selected "Support software installation in the lauched application". Then I ran the application and installed everything from CDT in http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.7 via the `Install New Software...` menu.

Why don't I have that menu entry "Convert to C/C++ Project"? It should be located under `File->New->Other...->C/C++` and it should also be visibile in `Windows->Perspective->Customize Perspective->Shortcuts->C/C++`.

In summary: I can see the menu in my 'host' eclipse, but not when running the eclipse application (plugin), though I installed CDT there, too, and everything else that could be found under "C++" or "Autotools".

The following screenshots show that there is no option "convert to C/C++ Project"

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Others can convert their projects to C/C++ Projects" --> Other what? Other plugins? Can you give an example?

Comment: I changed that first sentence to make clear that I'm talking of a common feature from CDT Plugin everyone can see and use.

Comment: Show a screenshot so readers of your question can see it too.

Comment: because they don't believe me?

Comment: What kind of eclipse plugin are you writing? Does it define its own project type, or something like that?

Comment: Yes it does define its own project type. But that should still allow me to convert to a C/C++ Project. I solved this problem by deleting my entire workspace and the runtime configuration folder. Than run the plugin and install CDT inside the running plugin again. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was most probably because of an erronous CDT installation. I deleted my workspace and the runtime configuration folder entirely, started everything new and installed CDT inside the running plugin again. After that the menu option "Convert to C/C++ Project" was there.

Answer (score 0):

I personnally upgraded from Eclipse 2019-09 to 2021-06, and I now have the `Convert to C/C++ Project` option.